# Lenovo Legion Y720 keyboard backlights not working

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I am trying to get the keyboard backlight working on Lenovo Legion Y720. I've tried some of the instructions that are out there so far nothing. Also upgraded the kernel to 4.15.9-041509-generic without success.

It would be OK to get at least one color working.

Running Xubuntu 17.10

Lenovo Legion Y720

At boot, the keyboard lights lid up for few seconds and then disappears.

All hints are welcome.